# Android Gradle, include child project to library aar

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an Android library project that has a Java child project to share code between an Android aar output and a separate jar output for pure Java projects.

The file structure is as follows

```
Root
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
    android_library (depends on java_shared)
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
    java_library (depends on java_shared)
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
    java_shared
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
```

I am trying to deploy the android_library as an aar and have it include the .class files from java_shared in it's final output.

Could someone help me achieve this using gradle?